# Adding --address=... option to dnsmasq using UCI in OpenWRT

Tags: dnsmasq, openwrt

I need to add a wildcard address record to dnsmasq running on OpenWRT.

If I were to call dnsmasq from the command line, it would look like this:

```
dnsmasq --address=/#/123.123.123.123 ...
```

I would like to use [UCI to configure dnsmasq](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp), but I am having trouble figuring out how to add this option.

One complication is that I have two instances of dnsmasq configured for my different interfaces. So, I have two `config dnsmasq <some name>` sections in `/etc/config/dhcp`. Unfortunately, I need to add this wildcard to only one of the sections, so I don't think I can use `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to specify this option as it would then apply to both instances (if I understand correctly). And, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an option that allows me to specify an additional `dnsmasq.conf` for just one of the interfaces.

My first thought was to add an `option addnhosts ...` to specify another hosts file just for one of the instances, but it seems like hosts files don't support wildcards.

Is this possible somehow? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is actually an undocumented list-option called `address` that does the trick...

```
list address '/#/123.123.123.123'
```

I guess that makes sense... :)

Comment: option might be there, but it's not being used by dnsmasq, at least in openwrt 19.07.0

Comment: Works for me when I add it to `config dnsmasq` in `/etc/config/dhcp`

Answer (score 1):

You can use DHCP and these commands to add an address in Dnsmasq using UCI:

To add the option address=/example.local/192.168.123.123 to Dnsmasq

```
uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].address='/example.local/192.168.123.123'
```

Save changes to DHCP:

```
uci commit dhcp
```

Restart Dnsmasq:

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

That's it.

You can also add other options using the same procedure, like conditional forwarding to Dnsmasq using:

```
uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].server='/example.com/1.1.1.1'
```

To show all the options, use:

```
uci show dhcp
```

To delete any of the added options, simply use:

```
uci del_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].server='/example.com/1.1.1.1'
```